# On high system load, what status code is safe to return

Tags: php, apache, http, web-crawler

I am wondering how can I issue a HTTP Status code, that will cause crawlers to try later for that content, as the system currently is running on high load.

Does a 304 status and no content display resolves this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should issue a `503` (Service Unavailable) with the `Retry-Later` option set. This seems to be an accurate solution.

See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html and http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Answer (score 1):

A `304` [HTTP Status](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) code means `Not Modified`.

If your content has not been modified since the last time the crawler came to its page *(that's assuming the crawler send a HTTP header to indicate when it came)*, I suppose it's OK to send a 304 HTTP status -- in fact, it would be the right thing to do.

But you should probably not send a `Not Modified` status code if :

- You cannot determine when the crawler came for the last time -- and, so, you cannot determine which version of your content has been last indexed
- Your content has been modified

Instead, **if your webserver is overloaded, the right HTTP status code would be `503 Service Unavailable`** *([quoting](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes))* :

> The server is currently unavailable
>   (because it is overloaded or down for
>   maintenance). 
> Generally, this is a
>   temporary state.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you answer with a `304` to an unconditional request, a client will likely just sort your answer as "generic error" (like 500). Why don't you send the status code intended for this kind of situation, `503 Service Unavailable`?.